# Is this non-homogeneous partial differential equation analytically solvable and if not what would be an appropriate numerical method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

> The equation is:
>
> $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{\nu}{(Ft)^2}\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial \theta^2} + \eta(\theta,t)$$
>
> where $\nu$ and $F$ are constants and $\eta$ is a function of $\theta$ and $t$. The equation is subject to periodic BCs in $\theta$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, and $h(\theta,0) = 0$.

If it is solvable could you please provide a hint to the right direction to solve it? If not what would be an appropriate numerical method? Many thanks.

Comment: Make a change of time-variable to make it a proper heat equation with a source and  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Inhomogeneous_heat_equation